# Using kryonet and amazon aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, kryonet

Does anyone have any experience they could share with deploying a kryonet server within an amazon aws elastic beanstalk?

And a more specific question - do you have to use a fixed ip-address or can it work via the beanstalk's url? If you need to use a fixed ip-address, how does this impact the beanstalk's scaling up?